# Page numbering adjustment in article

Tags: page-numbering

Question: Here i am working with an article (in which i am not using  `\titlepage` and `\tableofcontents`). My question is i wish to give page number from second page (after title page) by Page 1 of 10.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling,lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand*\headrulewidth{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\textbf{Page} \textbf{\thepage} \hspace{1pt} \textbf{of} \textbf{\pageref{LastPage}}}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \large
    \clearpage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
    \textbf{A research proposal}

\textbf{on}
\end{center}
\begin{center}
    \LARGE{\textbf{Tittle of the topic}}
\end{center}

\vspace{3.5cm}
\begin{center}
    \textbf{Submitted to}

    \textbf{XYZ University }

    \textbf{Place}
\end{center}

\vspace{3.5cm}
\begin{center}
\textbf{For the Program of }

\textbf{Doctor of Philosophy in XYZ}

\textbf{Duration}
\end{center}

\vfill
    \textbf{Prepared by:}

\vspace{0.5cm}  
    \textbf{XYZ}

    \textbf{Designation}

    \textbf{Department of XYZ}

    \textbf{Name of college} 

    \textbf{XYZ University} 
\newpage
\textbf{Table of Content}
\begin{enumerate}[\bfseries(1),left=0pt]
    \setlength\itemsep{2em}
    \item 
    \item 
    \item
    \item 
    \item 
    \item
    \item 
    \item 
    \item  
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of the quite lengthy `\cfoot{\textbf{Page} \textbf{\thepage} \hspace{1pt} \textbf{of} \textbf{\pageref{LastPage}}}` that will add a slightly larger horizontal page before `of`, you could use `\cfoot{\bfseries Page \thepage{} of \pageref{LastPage}}`.

Comment: To start the page numbering from 1 on the second page, you could use `\setcounter{page}{1}` just above the table of contents.

Comment: Probably it might also be a good idea to automatically generate the table of contents instead of manually adding it?

Comment: @leandriis Thanks for valuable comment. Once again thanks a lot

Comment: The question is: *why* are you using `article` if you need a `titlepage`, which is essentially what you're doing.